# How can I parse integer from a user provided string

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have a specification where the user needs to type in a string of pair of co-ordinates like:

```
{{2,3}, {9,0}}
```

these are the co-ordinates of a line on a 2-D axis.

I want to parse this user-input string during runtime dynamically in **C#** and enter these co-ordinates in a 2-D array. I know we can do hard-coded:

```
int[,] CoOrdinates = {{2,3}, {9,0}};
```

but I do not know how to get the user to type in a string and get the co-ordinates from the string to store in the array dynamically.

I'm using Console.Readline(); to get the user to input the co-ordinates.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: you probably want to use the System.Drawing.Point struct, it is basically x,y pairs

Comment: @Oded, as strings are arrays, I tried to pick up characters from their positions as:
'string inputCoOds = Console.ReadLine(); int CoOd1X = int.Parse(inputCoOds[2].ToString()); int CoOd1Y = int.Parse(inputCoOds[4].ToString());`
This is a bit ugly and non-generic, so I wanted a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regular expression ([`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class in C#) to parse out the bits of the string you want, and then `Int32.TryParse()` to convert the string to a number. [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good resource for constructing regular expressions, and [this](http://regexpal.com/) is my preferred regex tester. Good luck.

Comment: I would use `TryParse` instead.

Comment: @Daniel Agreed, `TryParse` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string s = "{{2,3}, {9,0}}";
            string p = "{(?<x>\\d),(?<y>\\d)}";
            Regex regex = new Regex(p);
            MatchCollection ms = regex.Matches(s);
            int[,] cood = new int[ms.Count, ms.Count];
            int i =0;
            foreach (Match m in ms)
            {
                cood[i,0] = int.Parse(m.Groups["x"].Value);
                cood[i, 1] = int.Parse(m.Groups["y"].Value);
                i++;
            }
```

You can use TryParse if wrong value in coordinates is expected

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer:

```
    public void IntegerReader()
    {
        string integers = Console.ReadLine();

        string[] split = integers.Split(',');

        int result;

        foreach (string s in split)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()))
                if (int.TryParse(s.Trim(), out result))
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @jlafay Did you tried in an Console Application? Because otherwise, yes it will give an exception because integers gets its value from Console.ReadLine()

Comment: I tried a string with the prescribed coordinate format that the OP specified. Did you try it? I think that maybe your split doesn't work.

Comment: As I said in my answer, I just gave a quick one using comma as a separator. Just to let him get an idea. He can change the separators list in Split menthod to include all the ones he want.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't super elegant but I think the result is what you expect

```
string coords = "{{2,3}, {9,0}}";
string matchPattern = @"\{\{(?<x1>\d{1})\,(?<y1>\d{1})\}\,\s*\{(?<x2>\d{1})\,(?<y2>\d{1})\}\}";

var matches = Regex.Match(coords, matchPattern);

int[,] values = new int[2,2];

int.TryParse(matches.Groups["x1"].ToString(), out values[0,0]);
int.TryParse(matches.Groups["y1"].ToString(), out values[0,1]);

int.TryParse(matches.Groups["x2"].ToString(), out values[1,0]);
int.TryParse(matches.Groups["y2"].ToString(), out values[1,1]);

/* Result:
 *    0  1
 *   -----
 * 0| 2  3
 * 1| 9  0
 */
```

Of course you will want to check that four groups were returned before assigning values to the rectangular array, but that should be easy enough for you to implement.